# How to get store data in transaction mails?

Tags: email-templates

How do I get data like the store owners address from the stoer config in an email template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the way to get the any config data you want via this answer :[Email templates: using store email address and logo in the admin back-end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/email-templates-using-store-email-address-and-logo-in-the-admin-back-end?rq=1)

and find the config identify id from table config_data

you want store owner address is "general/store_information/address"