# Variable for "Sales Representative" in Email Templates

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, transactional-mail, order-email

In all the email templates, I have:

```
{{depend store_email}}
    <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
{{/depend}}
```

However, this is outputting the **"Customer Support"** email address.

1. How can I change that so it is **show** the **"General Contact"** or **"Sales Representative"** email address in the template?
2. Why is the "Customer Support" email address the one that is output for the variable `store_email`?

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use this:

```
$email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

in your php file then make it as variable then use it

```
$templateVars = array('variablename' => $email);
```

then use your mail:

```
{{var variablename}}
```

Comment: Based on your answer, it sounds like it may be possible to change what is assigned to the `store_email` variable. Where might that be defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code in email template to get any of store config value :

General Store Email address:

```
{{config path="trans_email/ident_general/email"}}
```

Follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/email-templates-using-store-email-address-and-logo-in-the-admin-back-end?rq=1) for detail.